# serviceworker cache in conjunction with app cache still loading both?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, html5-appcache

I am writing a PWA and just got into service workers. I've implemented a worker-based cache but when my app loads, the regular manifest-based cache still gets loaded by the client (latest Chrome).
I thought that if a service worker was loading the cache, then manifest would be ignored?
Is there a way to explicitly ignore manifest cache if a worker is able to run?